# PHPUnit expect exception failing due to foreach warning

Tags: php, unit-testing, exception, phpunit

I want to test that a method called `foo()` throws an exception. The problem is that I can't get PHPUnit `expectException()` to catch the exception.

`foo()` looks something like this:

```
public function foo()
{
    $params = $this->readAndFormatConfig();
    // exception actually gets thrown in this method
    $this->method->throws->exception($params);
}
```

If I catch the exception manually it works fine, like this:

```
public function testFoo()
{
    $badConfig = new Config([]);
    $driver = new bar($badConfig);

    $exceptionThrown = false;
    try {
        $driver->foo();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $exceptionThrown = true;
    }
    $this->assertTrue($exceptionThrown);
}
```

If I catch it using expectException, like this:

```
public function testFoo()
{
    $badConfig = new Config([]);
    $driver = new bar($badConfig);
    $this->expectException(Exception::class);
    $driver->foo();
}
```

the test fails and I get this exception:

```
MyTestClass::testFoo Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

The output of `get_class($e)` is `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning` which surprised me, but explains why the first test works but the second doesn't.

I'd like to either ignore the warning and wait until a real exception is thrown, or get the original warning, not `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning`.

I'm using php 5.6.32 and PHPUnit 5.7.15

Comment: Seems like a problem with your `foo()` method... The error tells you there's a problem with a `foreach()`. PHPUnit probably makes an Exception out of the warning PHP throws, so that's why you're getting that Exception and not the one you're expecting.

Comment: ishegg In dev the warning is also an exception, but it's of the type that I expect. If I configure the class in dev the way I do in my test I get this exception ```Whoops \ Exception \ ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()```. Do you know how to stop PHPUnit from changing the exception class and throwing the original warning/excpetion?

Comment: What code are you using to turn PHP `Warning`s into `ErrorException`s?

Comment: [Whoops error handler](https://github.com/filp/whoops)

Comment: I'm guessing Whoops isn't actually ran in your tests so you're not getting the `ErrorException` you're expecting...

Comment: Right, I think I could solve this by either disabling PHPUnit from turning the warning into an exception or wrapping the warning in it's own exception class. If the exception was of type InvalidArguementException that would be fine, or If it didn't throw an exception at that point at all, that would be fine, because there would be a real exception later on from a call to a member function on null due to the foreach being empty. I'm not sure there's a way to run whoops within test cases. A flag to phpunit to suppress warnings or something would be ideal I think.

Comment: This is hackish -- I'm sure there's a better way, but try using [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to throw `ErrorException`s upon warnings (maybe in your bootstrap file?). That should sort it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166567/discussion-between-con-and-ishegg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following to boostrap.php converts warnings to exceptions.

```
function warningToException($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    throw new Exception($errstr . " on line " . $errline . " in file " . $errfile);
}

set_error_handler("warningToException", E_WARNING);
```

This allowed the following test pass.

```
public function testFoo()
{
    $badConfig = new Config([]);
    $driver = new bar($badConfig);
    $this->expectException(Exception::class);
    $driver->foo();
}
```

I think a better method would be to expect `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning` in the test as ishegg suggested.

What I ended up actually doing was making sure the object I was passing to foreach was traversable before entering the loop.

```
public function foo()
{
    if (is_array($x) || $x instanceof \Traversable) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        // return false;
    }
}
```

I think it makes more sense to refactor the application code in this case. What I'm really trying to test is that the function foo returns false if the application is misconfigured, so handling the misconfiguration properly seems like the right path in my opinion.

If you stumble upon this question for some reason and really need to convert warnings to an exception class other than `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning` this is how I did it.

Thanks to ishegg for pointing me in the right direction.